# Form space the input box

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

Hi i would like some help on how to space my name, email, contact, address input box to match the spacing for description as below in my picture. Please ignore my same class id i use below for my code as i am testing

[image]

here is the code for my form

```html
<form>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-form-label" style="padding-left: 20px; ">Name: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="Name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name" >
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-form-label" style="padding-left: 22px;">Email: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-form-label" style="padding-left: 22px;">Contact: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Contact">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-form-label" style="padding-left: 22px;">Address: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Address">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-form-label" style="padding-left: 22px;">Description: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Description...">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can your HTML be changed, or does it have to remain that way? The biggest problem you have is the `<div>` elements force new lines for each content; this can be solved easily enough but effectively you have a lot of surplus wrapping `<div>` elements. Do you want your `<label>` and `<input>` elements to line up, so they appear to be in columns, or do you want to maintain the flexible spacing you have in the image?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would help you if you use [Bootstrap form builder](https://bootstrapformbuilder.com/) to achieve this.

Here is a my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name:</label> 
    <div class="col-10">
      <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email:</label> 
    <div class="col-10">
      <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="contact" class="col-2 col-form-label">Contact:</label> 
    <div class="col-10">
      <input id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Contact" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="address" class="col-2 col-form-label">Address:</label> 
    <div class="col-10">
      <input id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="description" class="col-2 col-form-label">Description:</label> 
    <div class="col-10">
      <input id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-2 col-10">
      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Or [code pen](https://codepen.io/jankees/pen/jOGVKdJ)

Comment: but when i try and copy it to my html my input text box move all the way to the right ? is there a way to change it to the left with some space like what the bootstrap from builder show ?

Comment: Try adding a div class before the form element like this : <div class="col-md-4">

Comment: Glad i could help you out!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution in which you can achieve a uniformity (with align), is by adding a class to the labels that define a `min-width` that is equal to the width of the Description label.
This will force the shorter labels to have the same width at a minimum as the long label, and aligning them to the right will center them against the input elements.

For example:

```css
.my-form-label {
  min-width: 7rem;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

<div class='container'>
<form>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-form-label my-form-label" style="padding-left: 20px; ">Name: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="Name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name" >
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-form-label my-form-label" style="padding-left: 22px;">Email: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-form-label my-form-label" style="padding-left: 22px;">Contact: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Contact">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-form-label my-form-label" style="padding-left: 22px;">Address: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Address">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-form-label my-form-label" style="padding-left: 22px;">Description: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Description...">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `col` value to your `label`. Here, I use `col-2` so the `input` can be included in the rest of the `row`.

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<form>
    <div class="form-group row my-3">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Name:</label>
            <input class="col-sm-5" type="Name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"
                placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row my-3">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-2 col-form-label ">Email:</label>
            <input class="col-sm-5" type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"
                placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row my-3">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-2 col-form-label ">Contact:</label>
            <input class="col-sm-5" type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"
                placeholder="Contact">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row my-3">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-2 col-form-label ">Address:</label>
            <input class="col-sm-5" type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"
                placeholder="Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row my-3">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-2 col-form-label ">Description:</label>
            <input class="col-sm-5" type="inputEmail3" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"
                placeholder="Description...">
    </div>
</form>
```